# Unable to understand text

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am reading this book named "Asking the right questions" by M. Neil Brown. I am unable to comprehend the meaning of the bold text below.

> While absorbing information provides a productive start toward
>   becoming a thoughtful person, the sponge approach has a serious
>   disadvantage: It provides no method for deciding which information and
>   opinions to believe and which to reject. If a reader relied on the
>   sponge approach all the time, he would believe whatever he read last.
>   The idea of being the mental puppet of whomever one happens to
>   encounter is horrible imagery for a person and a community.
>   **Decisions become accidents of association**, instead of reflective judgments.

Could anyone please explain it using some form of grammar jargon, that will help in future to tag the question more appropriately,

Edit- Can you help me in understanding the below text too.
**Supposing the reason(s) were true, is there any way in which the conclusion nevertheless could be false?**

Comment: Decisions are *not* based on an informed analysis, and understanding of the problem.

Comment: The entire passage is extremely badly-written. The highlighted phrase is an exemplar of confused writing, where an author is trying to generate a certain rhythm and style, but (a) has no clue what he is doing so completely fails in the style exercise as such, and (b) all-but fails to communicate anything at all (you have to sort of "guess at what he probably meant").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd almost finished my answer when I saw @Rathony had provided one already. But it can't hurt to offer an alternative way of explaining your words in bold.

> Absorbing information like a sponge results in our **decisions being
>   based on an incidental association** with whatever we've read most
>   recently, instead of on information selected through reflection and
>   judgement.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think any grammar jargon is necessary to explain this construction which is X becomes Y.

X: Decisions (that you have to make about whether what you read is something to believe or reject while reading something)

Y: accidents (random events or happenings that are not intended) of association (a feeling, memory, or thought that is connected to what you read)

The sentence means

> While you have to make a decision or judgment on whether to accept
>   what you read or not when reading, those decisions are not made when
>   they should be made (and they become random events whenever there is any association with what you read). Those decisions should be made on a regular basis (not randomly) when it is necessary. Do not just try to read and absorb everything without thinking whether they are acceptable or not. You have to make such a decision along the way so that decisions can be reflective judgments.